# Datagrid with custom HeaderRenderer in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex4, itemrenderer

I have a datagrid in my Flex App, and I;m uisng a custom HeaderRender. This HeaderRender has a checkbox. How can I control the checkbox from outside the HeaderRender?

thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do with the checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not ideal, but you can dispatch a custom event from your header render with bubbling set to true. This will allow you to capture the event and reference the renderer with event.target.

There are other ways to do this using a lot more code (and a bit of extending) if you're looking for an "ideal" solution.